# Convert &Vec<u8> RGB Data to ImageBuffer Rust

Tags: image, rust

*Cargo.toml*

```toml
image = "0.23.12"
fltk = "0.10.14"
```

I'd like to save a rgb data as a jpeg file using rust's image crate:

```rust
use image::{RgbImage};
use image::ImageBuffer;
use fltk::{image::RgbImage, button::*};

let sourceImg = image::open("imgs/2.jpg").unwrap();
let rgb = RgbImage::new(&sourceImg.to_bytes(), x, y, 3).unwrap();
let mut prevWindowImgButton = Button::new(0,0, 300, 300, "");
prevWindowImgButton.set_image(Some(&rgb));

let rgbData= &prevWindowImgButton.image().unwrap().to_rgb_data();
//returns rgb data with type &Vec<u8>
rgbData.save("out/outputtest.jpg");
```

Gives error:

```rust
    testRGB.save("out/outputtest.jpg");
    |                         ^^^^ method not found in `&Vec<u8>`
```

Because .save must be used on an ImageBuffer. So how do I convert this rgb data to an ImageBuffer?

Comment: ImageBuffer is not a type inside the Rust standard library. What crate and what version of the crate are you using?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is to save a raw buffer to image file using the `image` crate you can use the `save_buffer_with_format` func:

```
use image::io::Reader;
use image::save_buffer_with_format;

fn main() {
    // The following three lines simply load a test image and convert it into buffer
    let img = Reader::open("myimage.png").unwrap().decode().unwrap().to_rgb8();
    let (width, height) = (img.width(), img.height());
    let img_byte_vec = img.into_raw();
    // The next line is what you want
    save_buffer_with_format("myimg.jpg", &img_byte_vec, width, height, image::ColorType::Rgb8, image::ImageFormat::Jpeg).unwrap();
}
```